# Дважды срабатывает вывод в консоль в цикле (Java)

Tags: java, циклы

При запуске цикла выводит сразу дважды строку "Введите через запятую Фамилию и Имя и нажмите Enter: ". Где что пропустил?

```
    int Weight=0;
    int Count=0;
System.out.println("Введите бла-бла-бла и нажмите Enter: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Weight = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите бла-бла-бла Enter: ");
        Count = scan.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Вводим параметры");
        for (int i=1; i<=Count;i++){
            System.out.println("Введите через запятую Фамилию и Имя и нажмите Enter");
            arrayList.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
```

Comment: Вы что-то пропустили, но явно не в этом участке кода

Comment: `scan.nextLine();` а до этого число читали? Буфер не очищали?

Comment: Вывожу полный код, который использую выше. Число до этого читал. Буфер не очищал.

Answer (score 0):

Изменил предпоследнюю строчку. Все заработало. Спасибо за подсказки.

```
    int Weight=0;
    int Count=0;
System.out.println("Введите бла-бла-бла и нажмите Enter: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Weight = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите бла-бла-бла Enter: ");
        Count = scan.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Вводим параметры");
        for (int i=1; i<=Count;i++){
            System.out.println("Введите через запятую Фамилию и Имя и нажмите Enter");
            arrayList.add(scan.next());
            }
```